# Unable to install on USB storage or SD card?

Tags: applications, installation, samsung-galaxy-y

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy Y (GT-S5360L),  which I recently factory reset. Now I have a problem: whenever I try to install most apps it gives the error " Unable to install on USB storage or SD card."  I Googled and found 2 solutions: one to delete a cache file, and the other to unmount the sd card while installing. The cache file was sm2dltmp or something like that located in either /sdcard/.android_secure or /mnt/secure/asec. I used rooted terminal emulator to look in both and I did not find the file. I did however, find a bunch of .asec files for apps I used to have before I reset my phone. I moved those to a backup directory, but still installing apps gave me the same error. So far I have only been able to install apps using the second method, unmounting the sd card. All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your "working method" shows the trouble must have to do with your SDCard. You could try with a new/blank card, which then should work. Investigate your current card using a card reader on your PC, and transfer your media files (and stuff you can identify and need) over to the new card, and skip content you cannot identify. If afterwards you don't miss anything, you should be fine.

Comment: I backed up my sd card data and reformatted (without restoring the data yet) and the Play Store STILL gives me the same error.

Comment: Woah... that's really strange. I've no idea what that might be then. Wait: With the SDCard mounted, can you write to it from the Galaxy Y? Maybe there's some strange problem preventing it being mounted r/w.

Comment: Yes I can still write to it

Comment: And with a different card it does not work either? -- Well, not really a solution, but maybe a work-around: You could try setting the preferred install location to either phone storage (0) or internal SD (1) using `adb shell pm set-Install-Location 0` (resp. `1`). Then Playstore should install most apps there even if the card is present.

Comment: I have not tried a different card but I suspect it will not work. Installing everything on internal storage isn't really working out as my phone has 200MB internal storage total.

Comment: Well, suspicion is one thing. But you won't know for sure before you've tried. If the problem persists with a different card, it's clearly a case for service.